# Nginx location = not working

Tags: nginx

I have two sites that I need to serve: a static one and a dynamic one (Rails app, doesn't really matter actually). I'm thinking about the following:

requests to domain.com/ => Static website

requests to domain.com/anything => Dynamic website

[Nginx's location directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) seems perfect for this situation:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.domain.com *.domain.com;

  # Static match. Any exact match enters here
  location = / {
    root /link/to/static/folder;
    index index.html;
  }

  # Dynamic match
  location / {
    root /link/to/dynamic/folder;
    proxy_pass unix_socket_defined_above;
  }
}
```

But whenever I make a request to domain.com it gets directed to the dynamic match. What am I missing?

**Edit:** Although it is not optimal, I'm achieving the desired functionality with the following declarations:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com .domain.com;

  # Static match. Any exact match enters here
  location = / {
    root /link/to/static/folder;
    index index.html;
  }

  # Dynamic match, make sure the URL has
  # characters after the server name
  location ~ ^/..* {
    root /link/to/dynamic/folder;
    proxy_pass unix_socket_defined_above;
  }
}
```

but I'm sure there's a "right way" to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you sure you restarted nginx? Cleared your browser cache?

Comment: Yes, full restart (sudo service nginx restart), testing with curl (doesn't have a cache, right?) and a browser with private window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `server_name` directive doesn't match `domain.com`.

The `*.domain.com` form is redundant with `www.domain.com` and doesn't match `domain.com`. Use `server_name .domain.com` instead.

As a consequence, if you have an explicit default server block or a server block handling requests for other domains included before this one, then your requests are processed in it.

Now if that's not the case, then it does indeed process `domain.com/` and `domain.com/anything` requests, implicitely being your default server block. In this case, the `index.html` file is served by the second location block since the `index` directive will issue an **[internal redirect](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index)**.

So you need to change this :

```
location = / {
    root /link/to/static/folder;
    index index.html;
}
```

To this :

```
location ~ /(?:index.html)?$ {
    root /link/to/static/folder;
    index index.html;
}
```

Comment: Changed to `server_name .domain.com;`, I don't have a default server, `/etc/nginx$ grep -nrI default .` returns nothing. No luck so far.

Comment: @jlhonora See the updated answer.